# Angular Reactive Form - How to add subscribe valueChanges to a single control inside Form Control in Form Array

Tags: angular, form-control, formarray

In Angular Reactive Forms I have form control "name" and form array control "skills", I can add `valueChange` subscribe to whole skills, but is there any way to add `valueChange` subscribe to "skillname" alone which is inside "skills".

```
this.exp = this.fb.group({
name: [null, Validators.required],
skills: this.fb.array([
  {
    skillname: 'java',
    experience: 2
  },
  {
    skillname: 'python',
    experience: 2
  }
]})})
```

Example:

```
this.exp.skills.valueChanges.subscribe(skills=>
          { //sample code });
```

But I need to listen to skillname:

```
this.exp.skills[0].skillname.valueChanges.subscribe(name=>
          { //sample code });
```

Like this, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use get and at functions.

```
this.exp.skills.at(yourindex).skillname.valueChanges.subscribe(name=>
          { //sample code });
```

would be

```
this.exp.get('skills').at(yourIndex).get('skillname').valueChanges.subscribe(name=> {});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.exp.get('skillName').valueChanges.subscribe(val=>{
  console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: How will that work, You have skillNames inside skill array.

Comment: Your correct I did not see that. Every element in array must contain a form group in reactive forms. and within that form group one can listen to events. Listen to all changes outside the inner formgroups might get complicated